# Simple Delegate Between View Controller and UIView Isn't Working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, delegates, xcode4.2

So I am using a simple delegate to access a function from a main view controller when a button is pressed on a subview that is generated as an overlay on top of the main view.  For some reason the function that is defined in the source view controller isn't being executed.  I have done this 100 times and feel like I am just missing something stupid.  Here is the code how come this isn't working?

Source ViewController's.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ProfileSettingsViewController.h"
#import "ImageViewer.h"

@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, subViewDelegate>
```

Source viewController.m:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ImageViewer.h"
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface ProfileViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, subViewDelegate>

@end

//where the ImageViewer object is defined    
@implementation ProfileViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    ImageViewer *loadImageViewer;
}

//where the UIView is initialized
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer view] == _profilePic)
    {
        loadImageViewer = [ImageViewer alloc];
        [loadImageViewer loadImageIntoViewer:self imageToLoad:_profilePic.image];
    }
    else if ([gestureRecognizer view] == _coverPhoto)
    {

    }
}
```

Destination View's.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@protocol subViewDelegate
-(void)photoFromSubview:(id)sender;
@end

@interface ImageViewer : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <subViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *mainImage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIViewController *parentView;

- (void)fromCameraRoll;
- (void)takePhoto;
- (void)removeImageViewer;
- (void)captureImage:(id)sender;
- (void)uploadPhoto:(id)sender;
- (UIImage *)addBackground;
- (ImageViewer *)loadImageIntoViewer:(UIViewController *)superView imageToLoad:(UIImage *)imageToLoad;

@end
```

Destination View's.m

```
#import "ImageViewer.h"

@implementation ImageViewer : UIView

//synthesize properties
@synthesize mainImage = _mainImage;
@synthesize parentView = _parentView;

//initialize the image viewer
- (ImageViewer *)loadImageIntoViewer:(UIViewController *)superView imageToLoad:(UIImage *)imageToLoad
{
    //create a new view with the same frame size as the superView
    ImageViewer *imageViewer = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithFrame:superView.view.bounds];
    _mainImage = imageToLoad;
    _parentView = superView;

    //if something's gone wrong, abort!
    if(!imageViewer)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    //add all components and functionalities to the program
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imageViewer addBackground]];
    background.alpha = 0.85;
    [imageViewer addSubview:background];
    [imageViewer addSubview:[imageViewer addImageToView:_mainImage superView:superView.view]];
    [imageViewer addSubview:[imageViewer addButtonToView:(superView.view.bounds.origin.x + 10.0) yPos:(superView.view.bounds.origin.x + 10.0) buttonAction:@selector(back:) buttonTitle:@"Back"]];
    [imageViewer addSubview:[imageViewer addButtonToView:(superView.view.bounds.origin.x + 10.0) yPos:((superView.view.center.y/2) + 270.0) buttonAction:@selector(captureImage:) buttonTitle:@"Camera"]];
    [imageViewer addSubview:[imageViewer addButtonToView:(superView.view.bounds.origin.x + 105.0) yPos:((superView.view.center.y/2) + 270.0) buttonAction:@selector(uploadPhoto:) buttonTitle:@"Upload"]];
    [imageViewer addSubview:[imageViewer addButtonToView:(superView.view.bounds.origin.x + 200.0) yPos:((superView.view.center.y/2) + 270.0) buttonAction:@selector(rotatePhoto:) buttonTitle:@"Rotate"]];
    [superView.view addSubview:imageViewer];

    return imageViewer;
}

//call delegate method
- (void)captureImage:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate photoFromSubview:self];
}
```

I have screwed something up haven't I?

Comment: can you check the delegate address in - (void)captureImage:(id)sender and verify that it is the same value as the parent view ? How does that compare to the property @property (nonatomic, copy) UIViewController *parentView; defined in the subview ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to debug this is to use breakpoints and see what gets invoked, and what doesn't (and check if your delegate is properly set). Of the top of my head, I would say you either forgot the set the delegate or possibly an outlet if you're using IB.

Edit: Ok, It seems to me now that your delegate property is in the wrong class. That property should be in your subview, and when creating that subview from your superview, you should set the delegate properly, something like this:

```
mySubview.delegate = self;
```

Comment: What is required to set the delegate?

Comment: I've edited the comment, it seems to me that you placed the delegate property in the wrong class.

Comment: the delegate property is already in the subview the subview is the destination the ImageViewer.  The ImageViewer adds its self as sub view when a function is called

Comment: should I just post the full source I have been at this for about 6 hours and it usually takes 10 minutes im literally pulling my hair out and would sell most of my internal organs to have this experience over

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your ProfileViewController.h you are missing a declaration of ImageViewer

```
@property (nonatomic, weak)  ImageViewer *imageViewer;
```

And in your ProfileViewController.m you need to set the delegate.

```
self.imageViewer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to post the code I think it is because I am loading the subview a really odd way.  Tips on how to do it properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was only using it as a local variable when I put it as a property (nonatomic, weak)  ImageViewer *imageViewer it doesn't load property (nonatomic, strong)  ImageViewer *imageViewer works but I the delegate still doesn't work @VGruenhagen

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the destination delegate to self.

```
ImageViewer *imageViewer = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithFrame:superView.view.bounds];
imageViewer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I know get the following run time exception -[ImageViewer photoFromSubview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c585ff0 @MarkM

Answer (score 0):

When you have a UIView that loads its self after you hace initialized the object and called the load method you set the delegate by using.

```
imageViewer.delegate = superView;
```

Where imageView is the newly initialized view not to be confused with the object self (self.delegate = superView isn't the same) and where superView is the is the parent view creating the UIView.

Now my last question would be is there a better way to do what I have done?  I feel like I have over complicated the situation.

Comment: I actually ended up using the Init to do a lot of stuff I was doing in the LoadImageIntoViewer function made things a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem in exactly same scenario.
After doing some brain storming i found the issue and resolved successfully.

The problem is scope of UIView object. So to resolve this create a global object of view in .h file and use it as your target object.

```
@interface profilePageViewController : parentViewController<PhotoUploadViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,ConnectionsDelegate>
{
    PhotoUploadView *photoUploadView;
```

And it will work very sure, You can also try to by printing the object to and you will find two different objects.One at time of init and other in delegate call.